# Area between common region between two intersecting circles

Tags: geometry, solution-verification, triangles, circles

Two circled with radius $2R$ and $\sqrt{2}R$ intersect each other at points $A$ and $B$. The centres of both the circles are on the same side of $AB$. $O$ is the centre of the bigger circle and $\angle{AOB}$ is $60^\circ$. Find the area of the common region between two cirlces.

I solved this problem two times and every time I came to the same solution of $R^2(2\pi-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2})$. However the answer provided is $R^2(\frac{13\pi}{6}+1-\sqrt{3})$ and unable to get to the same. Can someone please help with a solution for this? Please help !

[image]

PS : I am sorry as I am not able to put my solution approach here as I can not put up a figure to show my calculations.

Comment: A picture would be nice. Are you sure $O$ is the center of the bigger circle?

Comment: @Vasya : yeah..that's what mentioned in the question.

Comment: Added a picture.

Comment: So $AB=2R$ and $AD=R$ then $CD=R$ Does not make sense, does it?

Comment: yeah..it does not make sense...it's not possible..

Comment: maybe this image is little bit wrong...the smaller circle circumference will not pass $O$...try in that case..

Comment: It does not matter, if $AD=CD$ then $\angle ACB$ is a right angle and $AB$ is the diameter of the small circle. Still does not make sense. Where is this problem coming from?

Comment: yeah you are right ! Did you get any other answer? what's your answer?

Comment: Well $AB$ cannot be $2R$ and $2\sqrt 2 R$ at the same time so there is no answer. Something is wrong with the problem statement.

Comment: I have obtained the "provided" answer. You should provide your solution to identify your error.

Comment: A drawing to the scale helps to clarify a lot of details :-)

Answer (score 0):

Simplify the process with $R=1$

$AO'=\sqrt 2,AE=1,EO'=1", $ $\triangle AEO'$ is a $45^\circ-90^\circ-45^\circ$ triangle.

\begin{align}S_{ADE}=S_{ADO}-S_{AEO}=\frac{\pi}{3}-\frac{\sqrt 3}{2}\end{align}

\begin{align}S_{ACD}=S_{AO'C}-S_{ADE}-S_{AEO'}=\frac{\pi}{4}-(\frac{\pi}{3}-\frac{\sqrt 3}{2})-\frac{1}{2}=\sqrt3-\frac{\pi}{12}-\frac{1}{2}\end{align}

\begin{align}S=2\pi-\sqrt 3+\frac{\pi}{6}+1=\frac{13\pi}{6}-\sqrt 3+1\end{align}

Scale back R:  \begin{align}S=R^2(\frac{13\pi}{6}-\sqrt 3+1)\end{align}

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MdAcQ.png]

Comment: So $EO'=1$, $O'O=4-2\sqrt 3$, $EO'+O'O=5-2\sqrt 3$ but using Pythagoras, $EO=\sqrt 3$. Does not make sense.

Comment: $AO'=\sqrt 2,AE=1,EO'=1", $ $\triangle AEO'$ is a 45$\circ$-90$\circ$-45$\circ$ triangle.

Comment: Yes, but use law of cosines to calculate $O'O$ and you will see that numbers do not add up.

Comment: @Vasya, it is easier to check with law of sine for $\triangle AO’O$  to find O O’. It is consistent. Make sure you have angles right.